# how to retrieve one column with sum of hours

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

The below query is working perfect but it return two rows of hours which I don't want

```
SELECT
    USERINFO.name, USERINFO.BADGENUMBER, 
    departments.deptname, APPROVEDHRS.hours,
    sum(workingdays) as workingdays,TotalWorkingDays
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT 
         (DATEDIFF(DAY, '2014-06-01', '2014-06-30') + 1) -
          DATEDIFF(WEEK, '2014-06-01', '2014-06-30') * 2 - 
          (CASE WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, '2014-06-01') = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) - 
          (CASE WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, '2014-06-30') = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TotalWorkingDays, 
         COUNT(DISTINCT DATEADD(d, 0,DATEDIFF(d, 0, CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME))) AS workingdays,
         USERINFO.BADGENUMBER, USERINFO.NAME, hours
     FROM  
         USERINFO 
     LEFT JOIN 
         CHECKINOUT ON USERINFO.USERID = CHECKINOUT.USERID 
     LEFT JOIN 
         departments ON departments.deptid = userinfo.DEFAULTDEPTID
         left join APPROVEDHRS on APPROVEDHRS.userid = userinfo.userid AND 
(APPROVEDHRS.DATE >='2014-06-01') AND (APPROVEDHRS.DATE <='2014-06-30')
     WHERE
         (DEPARTMENTS.DEPTNAME = 'xyz') 
         AND (CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME >= '2014-06-01') 
         AND (CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME <= '2014-06-30') 
     GROUP BY 
         hours, USERINFO.BADGENUMBER, deptname, USERINFO.NAME,
         CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME, 103)) blue
GROUP BY 
    name, BADGENUMBER, workingdays, TotalWorkingDays, deptname, hours
```

The output of above query :

```
name    BADGENUMBER     deptname        hours   
---------------------------------------------------
abc     1111             xyz            00:07:59    
abc     1111             xyz            00:08:00    
pqr     2222             qwe            NULL
```

Now the total hours (`APPROVEDHRS` table) in table is :

```
BADGENUMBER     NAME    DATE        HOURS
-------------------------------------------------
1111            xyz  2014-06-15     00:07:59
1111            xyz  2014-06-14     00:08:00
1111            xyz  2014-07-14     00:10:00
```

I am fetching record from 2014-06-01 to 2014-06-30

So I want the below output:

```
name       BADGENUMBER      deptname        hours   
--------------------------------------------------------       
    abc     1111             xyz            00:15:59    

    pqr     2222            qwe             NULL
```

Help me to get this desired output.

Thank you

Comment: Your output doesn't match the query.  The `select` has more columns than your sample output.

Comment: @GordonLinoff. i have not display other columns in output ..but it is in my query

Comment: SQL Server has a `time` data type but this represents a *time of day*, not a *time interval*. Although both often can look the same, they are logically quite different things. For starters, it doesn't make sense to add two times of day together (whereas it makes sense to add a time interval to a time of day or to add two time intervals together). The cleanest thing to do is to decide what granularity you want to work with - hours, minutes or seconds, convert your data into `int`s that represent the total of the granularity, and then work with `int`s exclusively.

Comment: What is the data type of the hours field in APPROVEDHRS?  DATETIME, TIME, VARCHAR, etc. ...

Comment: @AHiggins...do you know answer of it?

Comment: Why do you need to include in your `GROUP BY` `WorkingDays` and `TotalWorkingDays`?

Comment: i have these kind of column which must be to do group by...i have not display these fields here.

Answer (score 0):

You must `GROUP BY name, badgenumber, deptname`.

Comment: thanks for your answer but please add the code sample showing your suggestion in action

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Select  
name,badgenumber,deptname,
Hours=
    Convert(varchar,SUM(convert(int,PARSENAME(replace(hours,':','.'),3))) +SUM(convert(int,PARSENAME(replace(hours,':','.'),2))) /60)+':'+
    Convert(varchar,SUM(convert(int,PARSENAME(replace(hours,':','.'),2))) %60+SUM(convert(int,PARSENAME(replace(hours,':','.'),1))) /60)+':'+
    convert(varchar,SUM(convert(int,PARSENAME(replace(hours,':','.'),1))) %60)
from    table -- Or joining Criteria
where isnull(date,'2014-06-01') between '2014-06-01' and '2014-06-30'
group by name,badgenumber,deptname
```

Comment: i am getting 1 raw with 15:59 hours ..it is good but i am also get another raw for 2014-07-14 with 31:58:0 hours...

Comment: can u tell me u r group by columns again

Comment: name,BADGENUMBER,deptname,hours...and if i remove hours from group by then it will give error for use group by

Comment: have u tried that , believe since u r using them in sum it will  not give any error.